# python appending a value to a sublist

Tags: python, list, append

I'm running into a problem in my program and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. To start I created an empty list of lists. For example:

```
>>> Lists = [[]]*12
```

which gives:

```
>>> Lists
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

However, when trying to append a value to an individual sublist it adds the value to all of the sublists. For example:

```
>>> Lists[2].append(1)
```

Gives:

```
>>> Lists
[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

Is there a way to append to just a single sublist so that the result would look like:

```
>>> Lists
    [[], [], [1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: You may want to look at [this](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-list-implementation/) to understand why it appends to all sublists. If you look at the second figure, you can think of the 12 elements in your list as pointing to the same object `[]`. Now when you append `1` to your `Lists[2]`, it appends to the shared list object. Hence, all elements in `Lists` appear to have the `1` appended.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

List objects are mutable, so you're actually making a list with 12 references to *one* list. Use a list comprehension and make 12 distinct lists:

```
Lists = [[] for i in range(12)]
```

<sup><sub>Sorry, I can't find the original duplicate of this exact question</sub></sup>

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem while trying to solve a topological sort problem.

try this:

```
Lists[2] = Lists[2]+[1]
```